# Google search results showing up a URL on its search which doesn't exist on the website

Tags: seo, google-search, site-search, search-results

I am using a keyword to display a website page on google search. After entering the keyword, on the first page of google, I am redirected to a page, whose domain is exactly similar to the website whose page I want to display, but it is showing a page which doesn't even exist on the domain. Also, as similar domain with spam characteristics is also getting displayed.

To practically demonstrate this issue, do follow the below steps.

1. Go to [this google search page](https://www.google.de/)
2. Type `dolce streichquartett` and click on search.
3. The 4th/5th URL has this link `http://www.dolce-streichquartett.de/?high_ry=/casinos/de/spielautomaten-casino-bregenz.php`, which is no where on the website and looks like spam
4. The 7th/8th link you see is `http://deonlinecasino.org/doc/kostenlos-roulette-spielen-spielgeld-ausdrucken.php`, which is exactly similar to the above with the title as the keyword but a different domain.

What is this issue and why is this happening?

Comment: [Cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28116530/1591669).

Answer (score 3):

This is a symptom of a hacked site.  The malware is adding this content.  It may be adding it just for Googlebot and then redirecting users somewhere else.

Google Webmaster Tools may be able to tell you more information.  Look at the [content keywords](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35255?hl=en) for your site:

> If **unexpected keywords**, such as "Viagra", appear on this page, this could be a sign that your site has been hacked.

[Google has an entire guide for webmasters who may be experiencing a hacked site](https://www.google.com/webmasters/hacked/).

Comment: Use the guide Google publishes.   It has a list of steps to take.

Comment: I read the guidelines and have not been under any of the categories mentioned. Plus, I also called up the hosting and they told me to flush everything, clean up and install it back. Do you think this to be the right solution? As the hosting people are like just clean up everything without a solution.

Comment: No this doesn't always fix it, also if you don't find the security hole which caused the site to be hacked in the first place, it will get hacked again. You need to work with a website hacking specialist to ensure the site and protected from future hacks.

Comment: @Max - Thanks for the useful inputs. I would like to know, is wordpress really this vulnerable that it gets access to such hacks? I mean, this has been very frequent on different servers where they were even updated, but strangely, without any plugins also, the code, somehow, became malicious. As you mentioned about website hacking specialist, where can I find one? Thanks again. +1

Comment: Yes word is very vulnerable to hacks, due to its open source nature and the share amount of wordpress sites out there. Google fix website hack, and check out the hack repair guy. I have used him before, and he has a good, personal service.

Answer (score 2):

Something fishy is going on there which probably involves a break in into that webspace.

With a little bit of poking you'll find that the casino pages are loaded from a directory named "/jumnmeyqgrqlyjvxtjmv".

I just called up the owner to inform her. She already knew and there's some cleaning up to be done which for some reason takes longer than I'd expect.

I assume it's just another designer who thought it'd be a good idea to run wordpress without any kind of update policy.

Comment: Also @David, what do you mean by `run wordpress without any kind of update policy.`??